# how to beautify foreach catching array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have created a benchmark class that allows the user to insert for example

```
$timer->checkpoint('2');
```

to check out some code for time,memory consumption and such....

at the end of the code she/he wants to test she/he has to insert

```
$result=$timer->result();
```

this gives out some data to public function result()

when I rdie **$resultmem**  it gives out

( [1] => 0.038664817810059 [2] => 0.038440942764282 [3] => 0.0019619464874268 )
(the code is below)
I would like to beautify it so I gives out for e.g.

Checkpoint 1 = 0.038664817810059

Checkpoint 2 = 0.038440942764282

...
...

depending on the number of checkpoints

How to do this? I have never done this before. Could you please help me out?
I apologize for my ignorance, but I'm a bit of a n00b

```
public function result(){
        $resultmem=$this->getAllMemoryTrackers();
        $resulttime=$this->getAllTimes();

        foreach($resultmem as $mem){
           rdie ($resultmem); 

        }

        foreach($resulttime as $time){
            rdie ($resulttime);

        }
    }
```

Comment: not sure exactly what your code is doing, but try using `echo 'Checkpoint 1: '.$resultmem[0];`, etc. instead of `rdie`

Comment: my bad...it is a built in function that allows to debug variables and such.....

Comment: @Rocket: Probably a function from some 3rd-party/company lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply loop thorough and print out the key and the value of each element.

```
foreach($resultmem as $key=>$val){
    echo "Checkpoint $key = $val";
}
```